# The acitivity is not declared in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-manifest

i had a problem, the Android Studio give me a warning which say:
"The acitivity is not declared in Android Manifest" this appear when i look on the Edit Configuration.

I see in another topic wich says that i have to put in androidManifest.xml

But i already did, and the Android Studio doesnt take it.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.drdower.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AplicacionSencillaInicio"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AplicacionSencillaResultado"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Which problem could be? 
Thank u!

Comment: Tell us the name of your Activity and also please post the "package" statement from your Activity java file.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy the code
2. delete the activity class
3. recreate one with same name
4. paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Place your whole package path

```
com.example.drdower.myapplication.AplicacionSencillaInicio
```

Then clean your Project.

**Also make sure you passed the correct `java` file name.**